# Nan::TryCatch will not intercept exception thrown in Nan::Callback from JS code

Tags: c++, node.js, v8, node.js-addon

Lets say I have a JS function which is simply throwing an error:

`function() { throw "Danger, Will Robinson!"; }`

This function passed in as an argument to a node.js addon and is used to construct a Nan::Callback (which should take care of making this handle persistent):

`// get handle to JS function and its Tcl name
    Handle<Function> fun = Handle<Function>::Cast( info[0] );
    Nan::Callback *pf = new Nan::Callback(fun);`

I'm having problems *intercepting* this JS exception from C++ when the `Nan::Callback` is called with `Call()` from C++:

`Nan::TryCatch tc;
    Local<Value>  retv = pf->Call( Nan::GetCurrentContext()->Global(), objc-1, &args );
    if ( tc.HasCaught() ) {
        printf("EXCEPTION:\n");
        ...`

In fact the script simply exits at the JS error and I never get back to inspect `tc` and the calls return value (`retv`) for any pending exceptions. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found it, this is most probably a [known Nan bug](https://github.com/nodejs/nan/issues/284). Quoting hankbao's comment on 27 Jul:

> I've just encountered a related issue. We're currently using electron
>   to pack our web app. There's a native node addon providing some
>   functionality for the electron app. Our web app will call the addon
>   and pass a js callback to it. The native addon store the callback in a
>   NanCallback. It setups a TryCatch before calling the callback. However
>   **the TryCatch always fails to catch the exception thrown by the js
>   callback**. It turns out that if I call the callback with Function::Call
>   instead of with NanCallback::Call(), exceptions can be caught

Based on this hint, I got the **issue solved**: I replaced the function handle from `Nan::Callback` with `v8::Persistent<Function>`, and finally got `TryCatch` to work as expected. The only catch: not using Nan means the code's prone to break as v8 is not exactly a stable API over time :)

Comment: Hi! Maybe changing to v8 style can solve this problem?https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45589254/invoking-some-callback-function-twice-leads-to-segmentation-fault-nan